# OpenLayers 3: Offset stroke style

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have LineString features styled by a single stroke. Some of these features represent two things, so in addition to the initial stroke color, I would like to have a parallel line next to it in a different color. This would be a no-brainer if `ol/style/Stroke` had an offset property like `ol/style/Image` does, but sadly, it does not. If I created offset geometries for those features, they wouldn't be visible from a zoomed out level. What are my options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can offset the geometries based on resolution

```js
var style = function(feature, resolution) {
var colors = ['green', 'yellow', 'red'];
var width = 4;
var styles = [];
for (var line = 0; line < colors.length; line++) {
    var dist = width * resolution * (line - (colors.length-1)/2);
    var geom = feature.getGeometry();
    var coords = [];
    var counter = 0;
    geom.forEachSegment(function(from, to) {
        var angle = Math.atan2(to[1] - from[1], to[0] - from[0]);
        var newFrom = [
            Math.sin(angle) * dist + from[0],
            -Math.cos(angle) * dist + from[1]
        ];
        var newTo = [
            Math.sin(angle) * dist + to[0],
            -Math.cos(angle) * dist + to[1]
        ];
        coords.push(newFrom);
        coords.push(newTo);
        if (coords.length > 2) {
            var intersection = math.intersect(coords[counter], coords[counter+1], coords[counter+2], coords[counter+3]);
            coords[counter+1] = (intersection) ? intersection : coords[counter+1];
            coords[counter+2] = (intersection) ? intersection : coords[counter+2];
            counter += 2;
        }
    });
    styles.push(
        new ol.style.Style({
            geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(coords),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: colors[line],
                width: width
            })
        })
    );
}
return styles;
};


var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source:  new ol.source.OSM() 
});

var source = new ol.source.Vector();

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: source,
  style: style
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
center: [-11000000, 4600000],
zoom: 4
  })
});

map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Draw({
  source: source,
  type: 'LineString'
}));
```

```css
html, body, .map {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/5.4.1/math.min.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

The intersect test prevents effects like this on sharp angles

[image]

For each each segment of the feature geometry the style function calculates parallel segments set to be 4 pixels apart regardless of the resolution (in this case line width and spacing are the same) for the styling geometries centered around the original segment (e.g. if three colors the center style line would follow the original and the outer style lines are offset by +/- 4, if two colors each lines would be offset by +/- 2)  Initially the parallel segments are the same length as the original but need to be increased at outside angles or reduced at inside angles so `math.intersect` is used to find the point where they should join to form a continuous line.  Finally for each color the completed linestring is used as the geometry for the color's style, and an array containing each style is returned.

Here is a second example where instead of simple colors and fixed width each offset line has its own width and stroke pattern.

```js
var white = [255, 255, 255, 1];
var blue = [0, 153, 255, 1];
var width = 3;

var pointStyle = new ol.style.Style({
image: new ol.style.Circle({
    radius: width * 2,
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: blue
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: white,
        width: width / 2
    })
}),
zIndex: Infinity
});

var style = function(feature, resolution) {
var widths = [10, 10];
var strokes = [
    [
        {
            width: 4,
            color: '#7af500'
         }, {
             width: 4,
             color: '#55aa00',
             lineDash: [7,9]
         }
    ], [
        {
            width: 2,
            color: 'black'
         }, {
             width: 8,
             color: 'black',
             lineDash: [2,14],
             lineCap: 'butt'
         }
    ]
];
var styles = [pointStyle];
var totalWidth = 0
for (var line = 0; line < widths.length; line++) {
    totalWidth += widths[line];
}
var width = 0;
for (var line = 0; line < widths.length; line++) {
  var dist = (width + widths[line]/2 - totalWidth/2) * resolution;
  width += widths[line];
  var geom = feature.getGeometry();
  if (geom.forEachSegment) {
    var coords = [];
    var counter = 0;
    geom.forEachSegment(function(from, to) {
        var angle = Math.atan2(to[1] - from[1], to[0] - from[0]);
        var newFrom = [
            Math.sin(angle) * dist + from[0],
            -Math.cos(angle) * dist + from[1]
        ];
        var newTo = [
            Math.sin(angle) * dist + to[0],
            -Math.cos(angle) * dist + to[1]
        ];
        coords.push(newFrom);
        coords.push(newTo);
        if (coords.length > 2) {
            var intersection = math.intersect(coords[counter], coords[counter+1], coords[counter+2], coords[counter+3]);
            coords[counter+1] = (intersection) ? intersection : coords[counter+1];
            coords[counter+2] = (intersection) ? intersection : coords[counter+2];
            counter += 2;
        }
    });
    strokes[line].forEach( function(stroke) {
        styles.push(
            new ol.style.Style({
                geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(coords),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke(stroke)
            })
        );
    });
  }
}
return styles;
};


var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source:  new ol.source.OSM() 
});

var source = new ol.source.Vector();

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: source,
  style: style
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
center: [-11000000, 4600000],
zoom: 4
  })
});

map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Draw({
  source: source,
  style: style,
  type: 'LineString'
}));
```

```css
html, body, .map {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/5.4.1/math.min.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Comment: What is `math` in the line `var intersection = math.intersect`? I don't suppose you meant `Math`, because there is no `Math.intersect`.

Comment: It works pretty great without that `if` block, thanks. Could you explain what your methodology is here, for the whole code. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the edit explaining the `if` block, but could you go through the math of the main section?

Answer (score 0):

I have a version of this that works - but not when I zoom the chart.

[Lines separates on zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJJ3m.png)

I plot  lines on the chart (from the database) and use our function to
draw the lines.

I tried to insert code here but my functions in the javascript
are not run. How do I use functions in code snipplets?

```js
function print_my_string( my_string )
{

   console.log( my_string );

}
```

```css
html, body, .map {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/5.4.1/math.min.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>

//  How do I use the java-script (Include before called...

<script>print_my_string( "Hello" );</script>
```

Comment: Why do you put the `print_my_string( "Hello" );` function call in a `<script>` block in the html instead of the code section of the editor?