# OpenLayers: Offset multilinestring

Tags: openlayers, multilinestring

Hi i have some problem for offset the coordinates of multiple line

For example my records is like this

| Record Number | Name | Start Point | End Point | Purpose |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Record 1 | Line1 | PointA | PointB | Bus |
| Record 2 | Line2 | PointA | PointB | Taxi |
| Record 3 | Line3 | PointA | PointB | Walk |
| Record 4 | Line4 | PointA | PointB | Cycle |
| Record 5 | Line5 | PointB | PointC | Bus |
| Record 6 | Line6 | PointB | PointD | Bus |
| Record 7 | Line7 | PointB | PointD | Walk |

i wish to write on openlayer map that will display

- 4 lines from pointa to pointb using different color  (bus=red,taxi=blue,walk=yellow,cycle=pink)
- 1 line from point b to point c
- 2 line from point b to point d

i try use this [OpenLayers 3: Offset stroke style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57421223/openlayers-3-offset-stroke-style) for example but i does not quite fit into it as for 4 lines from pointa to pointb will have different width size on map i not sure why.

i saw one [example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291745/display-overlapping-polyline-segments-as-multiple-lines-with-offsets) from leaflet is somehow like what i want but i want it to display in openlayer

Comment: This is the result of the basic method https://jsfiddle.net/n61oaxyf/ with equal spacing.  Are you trying to include the thin white spacer lines and black casing as in the leaflet example?

Comment: @Mike can i check how to display the name for each line?  i mean total there are 7 lines [Line1,Line2,Line3,Line4,Line5,Line6,Line7]