# Symbolization of lines on the OpenLayers map

Tags: javascript, styles, line, openlayers

How to make a complex symbolization of the line?

I do not know what this style is called, but you need something like this:

1. [broken line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBbTD.png)?
2. [dotted line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q88tw.png) (helped [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/411008)):

   ```
   [
       new ol.style.Style({
           stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
               width: 5,
               color: 'black'
           })
       }),
       new ol.style.Style({
           stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
               width: 3,
               color: 'white',
               lineCap: 'butt',
               lineDash: [9, 9]
           })
       })
   ]
   ```

I can't find information anywhere on how to set such a style, although they are often found on schematic maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number 2 can be done using a style function which sets a zigzag line geometry in the style.  This code is based on [OpenLayers 3: Offset stroke style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57421223/openlayers-3-offset-stroke-style/57421404#57421404) but instead of showing the parallel lines it works along the original line alternately plotting the closest points on each of the parallel lines.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.6.1/css/ol.css" />
    <style>
      html, body, .map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.6.1/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/9.4.4/math.min.js"></script>
<script>

function styleFunction(width, strokeWidth, color) {
  var style = new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: color,
      width: strokeWidth
    })
  });
  return function(feature, resolution) {
    var lines = [];
    var geom = feature.getGeometry();
    if (geom.getType() == "LineString") {
      for (var line = 0; line < 2; line++) {
        var dist = width * resolution * (line - 1/2);
        var coords = [];
        var counter = 0;
        geom.forEachSegment(function(from, to) {
          var angle = Math.atan2(to[1] - from[1], to[0] - from[0]);
          var newFrom = [
            Math.sin(angle) * dist + from[0],
            -Math.cos(angle) * dist + from[1]
          ];
          var newTo = [
            Math.sin(angle) * dist + to[0],
            -Math.cos(angle) * dist + to[1]
          ];
          coords.push(newFrom);
          coords.push(newTo);
          if (coords.length > 2) {
            var intersection = math.intersect(coords[counter], coords[counter+1], coords[counter+2], coords[counter+3]);
            coords[counter+1] = (intersection) ? intersection : coords[counter+1];
            coords[counter+2] = (intersection) ? intersection : coords[counter+2];
            counter += 2;
          }
        });
        lines.push(new ol.geom.LineString(coords));
      }
      var length = geom.getLength();
      var intervals = Math.ceil(length / (width * resolution));
      var coords = [];
      coords.push(geom.getCoordinateAt(0));
      for (var i= 0; i < intervals; i++) {
        coords.push(
          lines[i % 2].getClosestPoint(
            geom.getCoordinateAt((2 * i + 1) / (intervals * 2))
          )
        );
      }
      coords.push(geom.getCoordinateAt(1));
      style.setGeometry(new ol.geom.LineString(coords));
      return style;
    }
  };
}


var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source:  new ol.source.OSM() 
});

var source = new ol.source.Vector();

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: source,
  style: styleFunction(4, 2, 'black')
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-11000000, 4600000],
    zoom: 4
  })
});

map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Draw({
  source: source,
  type: 'LineString',
  style: styleFunction(4, 2, 'red')
}));

</script>

</body>
</html>
```